# Calling method from ActionListener

Tags: java

I have a JTextField called TEXTIN, when the return key is pressed, it should call my rollText method from the ActionListener which is in my constructor. I am out of ideas and have been trying to fix it for quite a while. This is the code from the constructor:

```
TEXTIN.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        rollText();

    }
```

The rollText method should take the text from TEXTIN and print it, letter by letter accross a row of 10 JLabels. I wont post the entire method because I know it works when given a predefined input but the beginning of it is:

```
public void rollText(ActionEvent e) throws InterruptedException{
        TEXTIN.setEditable(false); 
        String inputText = TEXTIN.getText();
...
```

Hopefully someone can help me out. Thank you.

Comment: What is `TEXTIN`?  Is it visible on the screen?  `rollText` will only be called when the `TEXTIN` component is actioned...which is contextual to the component type...

Comment: Its a JTextField, sorry

Comment: What is the problem? Is `rollText` not being called? Can you post the `rollText` method?

Comment: Sure, will edit the question. rollText isnt being called

Comment: So based on your update, it sounds like the instance of `TEXTIN` you're adding the listener to isn't the same instance that is on the screen, but's kind of hard to guess with the code snippet you've provided...

Comment: I've updated the question with part of the rollText method.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void rollText(ActionEvent e) throws InterruptedException
```

You can change this to:

```
public void rollText() throws InterruptedException
```

Providing of course you do not need the ActionEvent in the method. If you do, then change the following:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    rollText();
}
```

To:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    rollText( e );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
class MyClass{
    JTextField textIn;

    class MyActionListener extends ActionListener{
        private MyClass cls;
        public MyActionListener(MyClass cls){
            this.clas = cls;
        }

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            cls.rollText(e);
        }
    }

    public MyClass(){
        textIn.addActionListener(new MyActionLIstener(this));
    }
}
```

You need to create your own action listener and pass in the instance in the constructor of the action listener.

I don't have a Java compiler on my machine so the above code will have a few bugs but it should give you a general idea on how to proceed.